# Poisson Races: What is the Probability of a Tie? Is it monotone in the means?

Tags: random-variables, poisson-distribution

Consider a race between two Poisson distributed random variables. Conjecture: The race is more likely to be tied when the one behind gets faster.

If $N_1$ and $N_2$ are independent Poisson-distributed random variables with means $\mu_1$  and $\mu_2$, then $K=N_1-N_2$ follows the [Skellam distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skellam_distribution). The probability that $N_1$ and $N_2$ are equal ("the race ends in a tie") is $p(K=0;\mu_1,\mu_2)$.

$\textbf{Claim.}$ $\;$ If $\,$ $0<\mu_1' < \mu_1''  < \mu_2-1,$ then $\,$ $p(0;\mu_1',\mu_2) < p(0;\mu_1'',\mu_2)$.

But: Is this claim true?

---

**Update:** A friend and co-author has found a proof. I plan to update this post with the argument soon. Thank you to the commentators.

Comment: Do you want all strict inequalities here? It seems like what you want is $0<\mu_1<\mu_1'<\mu_2$ and then compare $p(0;\mu_1,\mu_2)$ to $p(0;\mu_1',\mu_2)$.

Comment: I suspect that the weaker condition $\mu_1'' < \mu_2 $ may not be sufficient. However, maybe this was not your question?

Comment: After messing around, I can see that it is equivalent to $I_1(x)/I_0(x)$ is greater than $(\sqrt{x^2+1}-1)/x$.  I can see this is true graphically, but I don't have a proof.

Comment: Maybe this will help: Rational Bounds for Ratios of Modified Bessel Functions, Ingemar Nåsell, https://doi.org/10.1137/0509001

Comment: Thank you for the helpful comments. A friend and co-author has found a proof of the result and I plan to post this soon, including a discussion of the inequalities above.